# Effects of psychologist's language in therapies of personal disorders

Tags: cognitive-psychology, psychoanalysis, therapy, personality-disorder, cognitive-therapy

Is there a dominant opinion about the positve or negative effects of explicitly naming the diagnosed disease and the observed symptoms (in the language of the psychologist) in the therapy of personality disorders, e.g. [narcissistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_personality_disorder)?

A general rule might be to remain always in the conceptual world and terminology of the patient. Or that some small dose of psychologist's language might be of help.

Most probably there is no single dominant opinion but several. Where do I find some expositions of such opinions, ideally in the form of a paper or talk, or as an answer here?

Finally, there may be meta-studies measuring the effect of (neuro-)psychologist's language in therapies of personal disorders. These to know would be perfect.

Comment: I believe that **opinion** on what should and should not be conveyed to the client can differ according to the therapeutic approach used in therapy (psychodynamic, person centred, integrative...) and therefore this question is broad. Maybe you could narrow this question by looking at a particular therapeutic approach?